# Normalizing sparse matrix by mean, should the mean be calculated excluding zero?

Tags: mean, normalization, matrix-decomposition, sparse, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I have very sparse matrix (70% sparsity) which I want to normalize by mean. I tried using mean both include and exclude zero. The histogram between count (y-axis) and value (x-axis) shows
[image: enter code here]

The value after normalizing is 10 times different. What is the logic to decide the mean should be calculated by excluding or including zero elements? I want to use this data for non-negative matrix factorization which sparsity/data distribution should be preserved.

Comment: What does zero represent in this case? Is it a lack of observations or this observation is not possible?

Comment: @user2974951 here all data can be quantified, zero represents no signal at that spot.